# Aggregating over randomly selected instances from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a four column dataframe:

```
prev (String) | curr (String) | n (int)
other-g | Abba | 5
other-e | Abba | 2
other-g | Bert | 9
```

There are multiple instances with the same `curr` attribute differing in their `n` and `prev`. I want to aggregate them over their differing `prev` attribute and count the `n` attributes.

It should result in something like:

curr: prev_A (59,3% -> share over all `n`), prev_B (23,2%), ...

The thing is I want to randomly select about 1000 different `curr` attributes from a large (> 1GB .tsv) dataframe. I would try to randomly select a row from the dataframe and then query for the respective `curr` to find all instances with the attribute but this seems fairly complicated and I don't even got it working. What would be a good approach to do this?

Comment: it starts bad since I see a 3 column data.frame ...

Comment: you should post the actual dataframe. not in its entirety obviously but at least the relevant portion. copy and paste from ipython shell works nicely. consider setting up `prev` column as an index. as a note, even for files 25Gb or so, pandas can parse through pretty quickly. you might not even need to randomly select. if you are worried about run time. if the random sampling is for statistical purposes well that's another story. i don't think this will be too complicated. look into `index`,`multindex` and `aggregate`.